# How to store GeoDataFrame to NetCDF file

Tags: python, geopandas, python-xarray

I want to save GeoDataFrame as a NetCDF file. Then, I can combine it with another NetCDF file later.

However, there's an error for saving the Dataset converted from GeoDataFrame. Here's a simple code and error info:

```
import geopandas

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
ds = world.to_xarray()
ds.to_netcdf('test.nc')
```

Error:

```
    ds.to_netcdf('test.nc')
  File "/public/home/zhangxin/new/miniconda3/envs/knmi_arctic_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1902, in to_netcdf
    return to_netcdf(
  File "/public/home/zhangxin/new/miniconda3/envs/knmi_arctic_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 1072, in to_netcdf
    dump_to_store(
  File "/public/home/zhangxin/new/miniconda3/envs/knmi_arctic_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 1119, in dump_to_store
    store.store(variables, attrs, check_encoding, writer, unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims)
  File "/public/home/zhangxin/new/miniconda3/envs/knmi_arctic_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/backends/common.py", line 261, in store
    variables, attributes = self.encode(variables, attributes)
  File "/public/home/zhangxin/new/miniconda3/envs/knmi_arctic_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/backends/common.py", line 350, in encode
    variables, attributes = cf_encoder(variables, attributes)
  File "/public/home/zhangxin/new/miniconda3/envs/knmi_arctic_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/conventions.py", line 855, in cf_encoder
    new_vars = {k: encode_cf_variable(v, name=k) for k, v in variables.items()}
  File "/public/home/zhangxin/new/miniconda3/envs/knmi_arctic_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/conventions.py", line 855, in <dictcomp>
    new_vars = {k: encode_cf_variable(v, name=k) for k, v in variables.items()}
  File "/public/home/zhangxin/new/miniconda3/envs/knmi_arctic_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/conventions.py", line 275, in encode_cf_variable
    var = ensure_dtype_not_object(var, name=name)
  File "/public/home/zhangxin/new/miniconda3/envs/knmi_arctic_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/conventions.py", line 233, in ensure_dtype_not_object
    data = _copy_with_dtype(data, dtype=_infer_dtype(data, name))
  File "/public/home/zhangxin/new/miniconda3/envs/knmi_arctic_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/conventions.py", line 167, in _infer_dtype
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: unable to infer dtype on variable 'geometry'; xarray cannot serialize arbitrary Python objects
```

Is it impossible to save `MULTIPOLYGON` or `POLYGON` in NC file? If you have any advice, I would appreciate a lot.

Comment: @RobRaymond's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70170293/3888719) does get the coordinates of the shapes into a netCDF, but now you'll have a massive netcdf with a cell for every single point in the entire natural earth shapefile, with all metadata about each shape repeated for each point, and you've lost the actual relationships between the points which make them polygons/multipolygons. why do you want to do this? is there a reason a GIS-native storage format such as shapefile or GeoParquet isn't suitable?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Hi, Because I have NetCDF files and each one has some geometry info. I suppose it would be convenient to save the geometry inside, instead of pairing geojson or shapefile.

Comment: got it. yeah I would not use the approach in that answer for this, since the data would no longer be indexed by region. if you really need to do this, you could convert the shapes into a string or compressed format such as [WKB](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_wkb.html). this will involve loss/compression, though. my recommendation would be to just point to the shapefile path in the metadata and read it in when using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand out the geometry to sequences of lat / lon.

```
import geopandas
import shapely.geometry

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

ds = world.drop(columns="geometry").join(
    world["geometry"]
    .apply(lambda g: [g] if isinstance(g, shapely.geometry.Polygon) else g.geoms)
    .explode()
    .apply(lambda p: p.exterior.coords)
    .explode()
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .rename(columns={0: "lat", 1: "lon"})
).to_xarray()

ds.to_netcdf('test.nc')
```

Comment: Nice method! BTW, it seems you make a simple mistake. It should be `0: "lon", 1: "lat"`.

Comment: I regularly get them wrong and need to fix :-)